# PHP insert image from outside document root

Tags: php

Okay, so I'm not so experienced with PHP, and I've been searching for hours for a way to access an image file outside of the document root. I know there are many answers to this question, sort of, but none that actually helped me.

So what I have so far is a folder structure like this (ignore the odd file names):

```
-img
    -imagez.php
    -logo.php

-public_html
    -files.php
```

I put this code inside of `files.php`:

`<?php include('/home/byonexco/img/imagez.php'); ?>`

If I access `files.php` from my browser, I see the content of `imagez.php`, as is expected.

My problem is, I want to be able to do the same thing with the file `logo.png`. The folder `img` is not publicly accessible, so I know I have to call the image with PHP.

How can I get `logo.png` to show on the page when someone accesses the file `files.php`?

Comment: The answers on that didn't help me so I had to post this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a very simple script like

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
if (strpos($_GET['img'], '..') === false) // check for quackery
    readfile('../img/' . $_GET['img']);
```

and access it like

```
/img.php?img=logo.png
```

However there are a couple disadvantages to this solution:

- Relaying the image through PHP **costs time** and performance
- The script is possibly **subjectible to exploits**, letting an evil person retrieve any file on the server

You're far better off with hosting images directly accessible.

Comment: This is a VERY bad idea. Allowing filenames to be specified in the request without parsing / sanity checks is VERY dangerous. Do not do this.

Comment: @user3791372 which is why i wrote the disclaimer. But fair enough, I've added a very crude check.

Comment: `/img.php?img=/..` will bypass that no?

Comment: @user3791372 No it won't. The condition fails as soon as `..` appears anywhere in the string and we're still prepending `../img/`, so an absolute path won't work either.

Comment: Thing is though, I can't access (for some weird reason) the img folder with PHP by using ../
That's why I was looking for other solutions.
I want to be able to stop users who aren't logged in from accessing certain images

Comment: @user3779981 In that case your OpenBasedir setting may not allow file access outside of your webroot. Check for that.

Answer (score 0):

As the image isn't publicly accessible, you'd need to get the image via PHP then output the image with the correct header

```
$image = file_get_contents('path/to/image.png';
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```